# Error Occuring while Extension Installation in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, extensions, system-configuration

Every time i am installing any extension in my Magento 2.0.7,It shows same error in Stores >> Configuration Page.

> Notice: Undefined index: id in
>   /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/module-config/Model/Config/Structure/Element/Iterator.php
>   on line 59

My Php Version is 5.6

Any problem in Magento Installation or PHP version.?

Full Error is

```
a:4:{i:0;s:136:"Notice: Undefined index: id in /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/module-config/Model/Config/Structure/Element/Iterator.php on line 59";i:1;s:6279:"#0 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/module-config/Model/Config/Structure/Element/Iterator.php(59): Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(8, 'Undefined index...', '/var/www/html/m...', 59, Array)
1 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/module-config/Model/Config/Structure.php(85): Magento\Config\Model\Config\Structure\Element\Iterator->setElements(Array, 'default')
2 /var/www/html/magento/var/generation/Magento/Config/Model/Config/Structure/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Config\Model\Config\Structure->getTabs()
3 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/module-config/Model/Config/Structure.php(108): Magento\Config\Model\Config\Structure\Interceptor->getTabs()
4 /var/www/html/magento/var/generation/Magento/Config/Model/Config/Structure/Interceptor.php(50): Magento\Config\Model\Config\Structure->getFirstSection()
5 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/module-config/Controller/Adminhtml/System/AbstractConfig.php(50): Magento\Config\Model\Config\Structure\Interceptor->getFirstSection()
6 [internal function]: Magento\Config\Controller\Adminhtml\System\AbstractConfig->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
7 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
8 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Config\Controller\Adminhtml\System\Config\Index\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
9 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Config\\...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Config\Controller\Adminhtml\System\Config\Index\Interceptor), Array, 'adminAuthentica...')
10 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(143): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
11 [internal function]: Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Config\Controller\Adminhtml\System\Config\Index\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
12 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(68): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
13 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Config\\...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Config\Controller\Adminhtml\System\Config\Index\Interceptor), Array, 'designLoader')
14 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Plugin/Design.php(39): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
15 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\Action\Plugin\Design->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Config\Controller\Adminhtml\System\Config\Index\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
16 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(68): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
17 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(136): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Config\\...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Config\Controller\Adminhtml\System\Config\Index\Interceptor), Array, 'adminMassaction...')
18 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/MassactionKey.php(33): Magento\Config\Controller\Adminhtml\System\Config\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
19 [internal function]: Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\MassactionKey->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Config\Controller\Adminhtml\System\Config\Index\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
20 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(141): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
21 /var/www/html/magento/var/generation/Magento/Config/Controller/Adminhtml/System/Config/Index/Interceptor.php(40): Magento\Config\Controller\Adminhtml\System\Config\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
22 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\Config\Controller\Adminhtml\System\Config\Index\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
23 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
24 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
25 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
26 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(136): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'install')
27 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php(69): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
28 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
29 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(141): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
30 /var/www/html/magento/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
31 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(115): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
32 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
33 /var/www/html/magento/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
34 {main}";s:3:"url";s:102:"/admin/admin/system_config/index/key/8fc39def664ca5361c316d328e370555b079f8bbb54b5b82e98472bdb289268b/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";}
```

system.xml file of extension is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="productslider_setting" translate="label" sortOrder="130" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>Mageplaza</label>
            <tab>Mageplaza</tab>
            <resource>Mageplaza_Productslider::productslider_config</resource>
            <group id="slider" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="500" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Product Slider Settings</label>`

                <field id="head" translate="label" type="button" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <frontend_model>Mageplaza\Core\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Head</frontend_model>
                    <comment><![CDATA[
                        <ul class="mageplaza-head">
                            <li><a href="https://docs.mageplaza.com/product-slider-m2/" target="_blank">User Guide</a>  </li>
                            <li><a href="https://mageplaza.freshdesk.com/" target="_blank">Helpdesk</a> </li>
                            <li><a href="https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-seo-extension/?utm_source=magento2&utm_medium=documents&utm_campaign=m2-product-slider" target="_blank">SEO Ultimate</a> </li>
                            <li>Increase 25% conversion rate with <a href="https://goo.gl/6chU3c" target="_blank">Layered Navigation</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        ]]></comment>
                </field>

                <field id="is_enabled" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Is Enabled Module</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                    <validate>validate-digits</validate>
                </field>
                <field id="loop" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Loop Slider</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                    <validate>validate-digits</validate>
                </field>
                <field id="responsive" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="30" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Is Responsive</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                    <validate>validate-digits</validate>
                </field>
                <field id="number_items_slider_screen_size_0" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="40" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Max Items Slider (Screen From 0 to 600)</label>
                    <validate>validate-digits</validate>
                    <comment>Should be 1 to most style</comment>
                </field>
                <field id="number_items_slider_screen_size_600" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="41" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Max Items Slider (Screen From 600 to 1000)</label>
                    <validate>validate-digits</validate>
                    <comment>Should be 3 to most style</comment>
                </field>
                <field id="number_items_slider_screen_size_1000" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="42" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Max Items Slider (Screen Bigger Than 1000)</label>
                    <validate>validate-digits</validate>
                    <comment>Should be 5 to most style</comment>
                </field>
                <field id="margin" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="50" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Margin Between Items</label>
                    <validate>validate-digits</validate>
                    <comment>Should be 10 to most style</comment>
                </field>
                <field id="autoWidth" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="60" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Auto Width</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                    <validate>validate-digits</validate>
                </field>
                <field id="nav" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="70" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Next/Prev buttons</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                    <validate>validate-digits</validate>
                </field>
                <field id="navText" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="80" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Change name of nav button</label>
                </field>
                <field id="dots" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="90" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Show Dots Navigation</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                    <validate>validate-digits</validate>
                </field>
                <field id="lazyLoad" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="100" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Lazy load images</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                    <validate>validate-digits</validate>
                </field>
                <field id="autoplay" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="110" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Autoplay</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                    <validate>validate-digits</validate>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

Comment: Extension that you are trying to install in that check system.xml file 
there must be some problem in that file so you are facing this error.

Comment: Am new to Magento 2. I don't know what error in my system.xml. I have post my system.xml above. Please tell any issue is there.

Comment: Please check my answer add that system.xml file and clear cache of your magento store and it will work .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to app/code/namespace/modulename/etc/adminhtml/system.xml

Add below code after `<system>` and before `<section id="productslider_setting" .....`

```
<tab id="Mageplaza" translate="label" sortOrder="200">
        <label>Mageplaza</label>
    </tab>
```

Clear cache and check again. Please let me know if it worked.

Comment: Thank u Soooo much Shyam.It's working fine,you solved my problem.

Comment: thats great Naga. Please "accept" the answer as well so that it will be marked as solved and will help others with same issue. Good day!

Answer (score 2):

Use Below updated code

In XML  I have added `<tab>` tag which was not there. befor adding it is in  we are referencing tab id like **`<tab>Mageplaza</tab>`** but actually tab with id  **"Mageplaza"** does not exist. so we have added it so now it should work fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
       <tab id="Mageplaza" translate="label" sortOrder="200">
            <label>Mageplaza</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="productslider_setting" translate="label" sortOrder="130" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>Mageplaza</label>
            <tab>Mageplaza</tab>
            <resource>Mageplaza_Productslider::productslider_config</resource>
            <group id="slider" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="500" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Product Slider Settings</label>`

                <field id="head" translate="label" type="button" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <frontend_model>Mageplaza\Core\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Head</frontend_model>
                    <comment><![CDATA[
                        <ul class="mageplaza-head">
                            <li><a href="https://docs.mageplaza.com/product-slider-m2/" target="_blank">User Guide</a>  </li>
                            <li><a href="https://mageplaza.freshdesk.com/" target="_blank">Helpdesk</a> </li>
                            <li><a href="https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-seo-extension/?utm_source=magento2&utm_medium=documents&utm_campaign=m2-product-slider" target="_blank">SEO Ultimate</a> </li>
                            <li>Increase 25% conversion rate with <a href="https://goo.gl/6chU3c" target="_blank">Layered Navigation</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        ]]></comment>
                </field>

                <field id="is_enabled" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Is Enabled Module</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                    <validate>validate-digits</validate>
                </field>
                <field id="loop" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Loop Slider</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                    <validate>validate-digits</validate>
                </field>
                <field id="responsive" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="30" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Is Responsive</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                    <validate>validate-digits</validate>
                </field>
                <field id="number_items_slider_screen_size_0" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="40" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Max Items Slider (Screen From 0 to 600)</label>
                    <validate>validate-digits</validate>
                    <comment>Should be 1 to most style</comment>
                </field>
                <field id="number_items_slider_screen_size_600" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="41" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Max Items Slider (Screen From 600 to 1000)</label>
                    <validate>validate-digits</validate>
                    <comment>Should be 3 to most style</comment>
                </field>
                <field id="number_items_slider_screen_size_1000" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="42" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Max Items Slider (Screen Bigger Than 1000)</label>
                    <validate>validate-digits</validate>
                    <comment>Should be 5 to most style</comment>
                </field>
                <field id="margin" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="50" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Margin Between Items</label>
                    <validate>validate-digits</validate>
                    <comment>Should be 10 to most style</comment>
                </field>
                <field id="autoWidth" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="60" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Auto Width</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                    <validate>validate-digits</validate>
                </field>
                <field id="nav" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="70" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Next/Prev buttons</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                    <validate>validate-digits</validate>
                </field>
                <field id="navText" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="80" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Change name of nav button</label>
                </field>
                <field id="dots" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="90" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Show Dots Navigation</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                    <validate>validate-digits</validate>
                </field>
                <field id="lazyLoad" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="100" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Lazy load images</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                    <validate>validate-digits</validate>
                </field>
                <field id="autoplay" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="110" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Autoplay</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                    <validate>validate-digits</validate>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue before. I should check all `system.xml` files in `etc/adminhtml` directory (third party) and each section must assign with an existing tab.